# Rename the property names and change the values of multiple objects

Tags: javascript, for-loop

In the object below, I'd like to change the property name, `thumb`, to `thumbnail`. I'd also like to change the values of the `title` to include `<span>` tags.

Here's my object:

```
var data = [{
    thumb: '/images/01.png',
    title: 'My title',
},{
    thumb: '/images/02.png',
    title: 'My title',
},{
    thumb: '/images/03.png',
    title: 'My title',
}];
```

here's how I'd like it to look:

```
var data = [{
    thumbnail: '/images/01.png',
    title: '<span class="red">title 1</span>',
},{
    thumbnail: '/images/02.png',
    title: '<span class="red">title 2</span>',
},{
    thumbnail: '/images/03.png',
    title: '<span class="red">title 3</span>',
}];
```

Here's what I've tried which doesn't work:

```
 var i=0, count=data.length;
   for (i=0;i<=count;i++){
    data[i].thumbnail=data[i].thumb;
    data[i].title="<span class='red'>"+data[i].title+"<span>";
   }
```

Comment: Are you asking for a way to do this _not_ by hand? If so, you should clarify in your post.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen asking for how I this would be done programmatically using javascript. I assume i need a for loop but can't get that to work. I'll clarify in my post.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
function changeData(data){
    var title;
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(data[i].hasOwnProperty("thumb")){
            data[i]["thumbnail"] = data[i]["thumb"];
            delete data[i]["thumb"];
        }

        if(data[i].hasOwnProperty("title")){ //added missing closing parenthesis
            title = data[i].title;
            data[i].title = '<span class="red">' + title + '</span>';
        }
    }
}

changeData(data);
```

**EDIT:**

I tried to make the function generic, but since you updated your answer to do very specific things, I've added the business logic to the function.

Comment: I'd recommend creating a new object instead of modifying the original

Answer (score 10):

You can [iterate over the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), set a new property in each object, and [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) the old property:

```
data.forEach(function(e) {
   e.thumbnail = e.thumb;
   delete e.thumb;    
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/pDAB7/) (check the output in the console).

Obviously you'll want to use a polyfill for `Array.prototype.forEach` if you want to support older browsers (there's one in the MDN article I linked to above, or you could just use a normal `for` loop).

Comment: thanks for pointing out the forEach loop. Can't wait until we don't need a polyfill for this.

Comment: @lbstr Hey I came across this Problem and do you know how we can do the same in controller itself  in MVC

Answer (score 2):

I have created a nice function to rename properties names: https://github.com/meni181818/simpleCloneJS/blob/master/renameProperties.js

**example:**

```
var sourceObj = {
    foo: 'this is foo',
    bar: {baz: 'this is baz',
          qux: 'this is qux'}
};
//                                the source, rename list
var replacedObj = renameProperties(sourceObj, {foo: 'foooo', qux: 'quxxxx'});
// replacedObj output => {
        foooo: 'this is foo',
        bar: {baz: 'this is baz',
              quxxxx: 'this is qux'}
    };
```

Since you are using Jquery you can use `$.each` function inside this function:

```
function renameProperties(sourceObj, replaceList, destObj) {
    destObj = destObj || {};
    $.each(sourceObj, function(key) {
        if(sourceObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if(sourceObj[key] instanceof Array) {
                if(replaceList[key]) {
                    var newName = replaceList[key];
                    destObj[newName] = [];
                    renameProperties(sourceObj[key], replaceList, destObj[newName]);
                } else if(!replaceList[key]) {
                    destObj[key] = [];
                    renameProperties(sourceObj[key], replaceList, destObj[key]);
                }
            } else if(typeof sourceObj[key] === 'object') {
                if(replaceList[key]) {
                    var newName = replaceList[key];
                    destObj[newName] = {};
                    renameProperties(sourceObj[key], replaceList, destObj[newName]);
                } else if(!replaceList[key]) {
                    destObj[key] = {};
                    renameProperties(sourceObj[key], replaceList, destObj[key]);
                }
            } else {
                if(replaceList[key]) {
                    var newName = replaceList[key];
                    destObj[newName] = sourceObj[key];
                } else if(!replaceList[key]) {
                    destObj[key] = sourceObj[key];
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return destObj;
}
```

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g2jzse5k/**