# React Redux rename nested object in API response

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am getting a response from my API and I'm trying to rename a nested object property for an array of objects in my action before I sent it to the reducer. Here is generally what the response looks like:

```
[
  {
    attributes: {
      name: "Item 1",
      price_cents: 1500
    }
  },
  {
    attributes: {
      name: "Item 2",
      price_cents: 1000
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

and I would like to change `price_cents` to `price`. How could I change this before I use it as the payload to the reducer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to walk over each of the values in the response array, and create a new object with the properties and names you want:

```
const actionCreator = (response) => ({
  type: 'ACTION_TYPE',
  payload: response.map((item) => ({
    attributes: {
      name: item.attributes.name,
      price: item.attributes.price_cents
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a filter to change attribute value, when the response succesfully returns, filter the response and reduce it.

JSON property name change : [Rename the property names and change the values of multiple objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819863/rename-the-property-names-and-change-the-values-of-multiple-json-objects)

JSON property name change (2) : [change property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483425/change-property-name)